# Get numeric values from based on specific substring phrase

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, substring

I have the alphanumeric text as below

```
 ID Textfield
 1  estimated left ventricular ejection fraction 60-65%
 2  estimated left ventricular ejection fraction is 55-60%
 3  Left ventricular ejection fraction is approximately 40 to 50%
 4  Fractional Short 50 %( 28-48) LV mass 83 gm (<220) systolic function  left ventricular ejection fraction = 52 %
```

I need to extract numeric values for the left ventricular ejection fraction

Output should be

```
ID Lowerbound   Upperbound
1   60            65
2   55            60
3   40            50
4   52            NULL
```

I have tried below sql syntax  searching on character  - its failing me for ID 3 and 4(For ID 4,its giving me as 50 but supposed to be 52)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(textfield,CHARINDEX('-', 
textfield)-1,10),dbo.udf_GetNumeric(RIGHT(left(textfield,CHARINDEX('- 
',textfield)-1 ),10))AS Lower_bound,left(textfield, CHARINDEX('-', 
textfield) )


,dbo.udf_GetNumeric(SUBSTRING(textfield,CHARINDEX('-', textfield)+1,5)) 
    AS Upper_bound
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your text in textfield,  is a free form text, I believe a simple logic cannot extract the number that you want. The approach that I would I take is take, who ever is creating this data (inserting), in that process I will laydown certain rules to ensure the numbers can be extracted properly.

Comment: Sorry to say that. But the actual issue is with the data structure. You should have created additional fields for holding relative numerical data. If you really have to use one field for all such data then follow any text formats, Like `CSV` or `XML` or whatever suites you, but don't raise such a loose data structure. You may also create your own little standard like `Frac='%';LFrac='60';HFrac='65'`

Comment: This is a pretty bad use-case for SQL.  Can't you use a tool such as Python for dealing with the text?

Comment: My approach below is going line by line and parsing characters after the words 'left ventricular ejection fraction' one at a time to see if they are numeric or not and then handling them accordingly.  Messy but should work for this situation. As @GordonLinoff mentioned above this is definitely a pretty bad use-case for SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't have the control of the text field. I agree this is bad use case but I am trying to find based on the requirement

Comment: @DanielMarcus Thanks you for your approach and code. I am debugging and testing the code

Comment: @user3594484, ok good - let me know if you find records it doesn't work for and i will adjust the logic accordingly

Answer (score 1):

This will use several `CROSS APPLYs` to get closer and closer. Some replacements make the string comparable, The first blank from the rear end is the border. The rest is rather easy.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT, Textfield VARCHAR(500));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'estimated left ventricular ejection fraction 60-65%')
,(2,'estimated left ventricular ejection fraction is 55-60%')
,(3,'Left ventricular ejection fraction is approximately 40 to 50%')
,(4,'Fractional Short 50 %( 28-48) LV mass 83 gm (<220) systolic function  left ventricular ejection fraction = 52 % ');

SELECT ID
      ,Rev
      ,substr
      ,CASE WHEN hyph>0 THEN LEFT(substr,hyph-1) ELSE substr END AS LowerBound
      ,CASE WHEN hyph>0 THEN SUBSTRING(substr,hyph+1,10) ELSE NULL END AS UpperBound
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT REVERSE(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(t.Textfield,' to ','-'),' %','%')))) AS A(Rev)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT PATINDEX('% [^1-9]%',A.Rev)) AS B(pos)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REVERSE(LEFT(A.Rev,B.pos)),'%','')))) AS C(substr)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX('-',C.substr)) AS D(hyph);
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this would work for your Upperbound issue, at least within the confines of your example data:

```
CASE WHEN RIGHT(TextField, 4) LIKE '%-[1234567890]' + '%' 
    THEN Left(Right(TextField,3),2) 
WHEN RIGHT(TextField, 6) LIKE '%to [1234567890]%'
    THEN Left(Right(TextField,3),2) 
WHEN RIGHT(TextField, 6) LIKE '%= [1234567890]%'
    THEN Left(Right(TextField,4),2) 
END AS UpperBound
```

But, your example data is seriously quite bad,m

Comment: FYI you can use '%[0-9]%' instead of writing out every number

Answer (score 0):

Please give this code a try and let me know if this works for your whole data set.  Assumptions here are:

1) Your numbers always come after the words 'left ventricular ejection     fraction'

2) There are no other numbers after the words 'left ventricular ejection    fraction' other than the values that define lower and upper bounds

3) Lower and Upper bounds always go left to right (small to large)

4) The name of your starting table is #temp

```
 declare @temp table (id int, field varchar(max))
 insert @temp

 select id, replace(right(Textfield, len(Textfield)-charindex('left ventricular ejection fraction', Textfield)+1),
'left ventricular ejection fraction','') field  
 from #temp 

 declare @holding table (id int, lowerbd varchar(max), upperbd varchar(max)) 
 declare @iterator int =1
 declare @prevfield varchar(max)
 declare @field varchar(max)
 declare @originalfield varchar(max)
 declare @number varchar(max)=''

 while @iterator<=(select max(id) from @temp)
 begin

 select @originalfield = field from @temp where id=@iterator

 while len(@originalfield) >0
 begin

 set @prevfield=@field

 select @field=left(@originalfield,1) 

 set @originalfield= 
 case 
 when len(@originalfield)>1 then substring(@originalfield, 2, len(@originalfield))
 else '' end 

 if  @field like '%[0-9]%'  
 begin
 set @number = @number+@field
 end
 if @field like '%[0-9]%' and @prevfield like '%[0-9]%'
 begin
     if not exists(select 1 from @holding where id= @iterator)
     begin
     insert @holding
     select @iterator, @number, null
     set @number=''
     end
     else   
     begin
     insert @holding
     select @iterator, null, @number
     set @number=''
     end

 end


end
set @iterator=@iterator+1
end

select id, max(lowerbd)lowerbd, max(upperbd)upperbd from @holding 
group by id
```

Comment: I don't think that  a loop (even worse with nested loops) is needed here. This is procedural thinking... Might be, that there are cases, where such an approach is appropriate, but in these cases I'd say, that `T-SQL` is the wrong tool.

Comment: So how would you propose solving this using tsql then? Op has a requirement to use sql server here and can’t use any other tool.

Comment: Your solution above is specific to those 4 sample lines.  I think the idea was to come up with a solution that would work in any situation no matter what text is provided after the words ‘left ventricular ejection fraction’.

Comment: Just Cut away everything before this Fragment? My solution looks at the string's end, without looking at the parts before.

Comment: why do you think, that this specific Text is so important?